# unable to insert picture above 399kb into varbinary(max) dataType in mssql

Tags: sql-server, jsf

Please I need help from someone possibly from balusC and or anyone out there.

I have been trying to upload picture files above 390kb into varbinary(max)  datatype in microsoft sql server 2008 but I can't, instead I get the exception below.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The text, ntext, or image pointer value conflicts with the column name specified
```

Am using primeface fileupload component to get the image needed.

The method am using to send the file into the database looks like this:

```
pstmnt.setBinaryStream.(2,uploadedFile.getInputStream.(),uploadedFile.getSize());
```

But when I try uploading files below equal to or below 390kb, it uploads successfully.
I have been making research on how to solve this and these various research led me into updating my sql server driver to sqljdbc4, and jtds.

I also tried enabling filestream on my database and the column that accepts the picture but it still does not work. Please I need help from someone, because I have been on this for up to three weeks now. ANY kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

its now working. it was actually my jdbc driver. I changed it to jtds as pedrag maric  advised but it wasn't working at first because I didn't configure it well enough to work with my app. Simply put, I didn't specify in DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:jtds:sqlserver/ blah blah blah);. Rather what I was still using even after I added the jar file to my classpath was DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:databasename","sa","****"); mehn!! I was soooo happy when it worked.